# Kafka-Neo4J-Connector: $lastCheck not updating if no timestamp is returned

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, confluent-schema-registry

I followed the quickstart-tutorial for the [Neo4J-Kafka-Connector](https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka/quickstart-connect/). The following source instance cypher

```
MATCH (ts:TestSource) WHERE ts.timestamp > $lastCheck RETURN ts.name AS name, ts.surname AS surname, ts.timestamp AS timestamp
```

inserts `name, surname, timestamp` rows in a kafka topic, if the `ts.timestamp > $lastCheck` condition is satisfied.

If I am removing the `ts.timestamp as timestamp` from the return-clause, then the `$lastCheck` parameter isn't updated anymore, so the where condition is always true and the whole graph is queried for every request. Is there a way to update the `$lastCheck` parameter without returning a timestamp? This would be great, especially for aggregations, if a grouping on the timestamp is not wanted.

**EDIT**

To illustrate the problem a bit better, I added the `$lastCheck` parameter to the return clause. So my first query

```
MATCH (ts:TestSource) WHERE ts.timestamp > $lastCheck RETURN ts.name AS name, ts.surname AS surname, ts.timestamp AS timestamp, $lastCheck as lastCheck
```

writes the following messages into my topic:
[image: Topic after first topic]

Here, I inserted the example `TestSource` nodes **twice** (after a short delay), to show the updated `$lastCheck` parameter.

> CREATE (:TestSource {name: 'john', surname: 'doe', timestamp: datetime().epochMillis});
> CREATE (:TestSource {name: 'mary', surname: 'doe', timestamp: datetime().epochMillis});
> CREATE (:TestSource {name: 'jack', surname: 'small', timestamp: datetime().epochMillis});

Now I remove the `ts.timestamp as timestamp` from the return clause.

```
MATCH (ts:TestSource) WHERE ts.timestamp > $lastCheck RETURN ts.name AS name, ts.surname AS surname, $lastCheck as lastCheck
```

The nodes in the database were deleted, and I inserted them only **once**. The messages in the topic look like this:

[image: Topic after second query]

The screenshot only shows the first seven, but these messages are printed infinitely. Sometimes the `$lastCheck` in the topic is also just returned by the second query as `-1`.

Comment: Removing a returned value should not affect the `WHERE` behavior. Are you sure you did not make any other changes to the query? Please add your new query to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I edited the question to give some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted `timestamp` from the source instance's `neo4j.source.query` value, but presumably kept the `neo4j.streaming.property` still assigned to "timestamp".

According to [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka/kafka-connect/configuration/), the optional `neo4j.streaming.property` property is:

> The name of the property that we need to consider in order to
> determinate the last queried record; if not defined we use an internal
> value given from the last performed check. We use this value for
> injecting it in the provided query defined in `neo4j.source.query` as
> `$lastCheck` parameter.

*I fixed a typo in the above quote.*

Try deleting the optional `neo4j.streaming.property` property so that the internal value can be used instead.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what happened. Removing the property resolved the issue